# Where are my HRs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

For some reason bootstrap's CSS manages to hide some (but not all) of my `hr`s at certain `width`s.

If you go to This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhtpLwtq/) and expand the output pane to be wide enough, you'll notice that the `hr`s between "attachment", "add attachment", and "Department" all vanish. Why?

How can I get them to show up at any `width`?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
        <div class="body-content">
    
    <form action="/Reports/Edit/5" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">    <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Report</h4>
            <hr>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ShortageFilledDate">Date Shortage Filled</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input name="ShortageFilledDate" class="form-control text-box single-line" id="ShortageFilledDate" type="datetime" value="" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date Shortage Filled must be a date.">
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="ShortageFilledDate"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ReplanClosedDate">Date Replan Closed</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input name="ReplanClosedDate" class="form-control text-box single-line" id="ReplanClosedDate" type="datetime" value="" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date Replan Closed must be a date.">
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="ReplanClosedDate"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Save">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-2">attachment:</div><div class="col-md-10"><a href="/files/d460e9b3-14c2-485e-88e3-2fba3de4863a.png">logo.png</a></div>
    <hr>
    <form action="/Reports/AddAttachment" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"><input name="reportId" id="reportId" type="hidden" value="5">    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Add_Attachment">Add Attachment</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input name="upload" id="attachment" type="file">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Upload Attachment">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <hr>
    
    
    <form action="/Reports/SendToDepartment" method="post"><input name="ReportId" id="ReportId" type="hidden" value="5">    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Department">Department</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select name="Department" class="form-control" id="Department"><option value="">Select Next Department Location</option>
    <option value="0">Production</option>
    <option value="1">DMRClerk</option>
    <option value="2">QualityEngineer</option>
    <option value="3">Stockroom</option>
    <option value="4">Purchasing</option>
    <option value="5">Shipping</option>
    <option value="6">Archive</option>
    </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Comments">Comments</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <textarea name="Comments" id="Comments" rows="3" cols="200"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Send to Department">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    
    <div>
        <a href="/">Back to List</a>
    </div>
    
    
            <hr>
            <footer>
                <p class="text-center">© 2016</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    
  
    
    </body>
```

Comment: You may have to create an overriding CSS script.

Comment: I hade the same issue with Bootstrap scripts and stylesheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because when not in smaller views (`xs`) the classes uses `float:left`

so the `hr` is being used after those classes, therefore must cleared before.

you can use bootstrap class `clearfix` for that

```css
.body-content hr {
  border-color: red
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="body-content">

    <form action="/Reports/Edit/5" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
      <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Report</h4>
        <hr>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ShortageFilledDate">Date Shortage Filled</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <input name="ShortageFilledDate" class="form-control text-box single-line" id="ShortageFilledDate" type="datetime" value="" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date Shortage Filled must be a date.">
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="ShortageFilledDate"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ReplanClosedDate">Date Replan Closed</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <input name="ReplanClosedDate" class="form-control text-box single-line" id="ReplanClosedDate" type="datetime" value="" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date Replan Closed must be a date.">
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="ReplanClosedDate"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Save">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-2">attachment:</div>
    <div class="col-md-10"><a href="/files/d460e9b3-14c2-485e-88e3-2fba3de4863a.png">logo.png</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <hr>
    <form action="/Reports/AddAttachment" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <input name="reportId" id="reportId" type="hidden" value="5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Add_Attachment">Add Attachment</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <input name="upload" id="attachment" type="file">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
          <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Upload Attachment">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <hr>


    <form action="/Reports/SendToDepartment" method="post">
      <input name="ReportId" id="ReportId" type="hidden" value="5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Department">Department</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <select name="Department" class="form-control" id="Department">
            <option value="">Select Next Department Location</option>
            <option value="0">Production</option>
            <option value="1">DMRClerk</option>
            <option value="2">QualityEngineer</option>
            <option value="3">Stockroom</option>
            <option value="4">Purchasing</option>
            <option value="5">Shipping</option>
            <option value="6">Archive</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Comments">Comments</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <textarea name="Comments" id="Comments" rows="3" cols="200"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
          <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Send to Department">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    <div>
      <a href="/">Back to List</a>
    </div>

     
    <hr>
    <footer>
      <p class="text-center">© 2016</p>
    </footer>
  </div>

  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

  <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just another pitfall of the bootstrap framework(one of the reasons why I kinda hate using bootstrap).

When bootstrap is included in an application, the styles in `bootstrap.css` **voluntarily/involuntarily overrides your HTML elements**. This is exactly what happened to your `<hr>` tags. As you can see in a browser debugger your HRs now will have the following piece of code coming from **bootstrap.css line 1140**.

```
//coming from bootstrap.css line:1140
hr {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 0; //this is causing the issue
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}
//coming from bootstrap.css line:1140
```

The `border: 0` is causing the issue in this case, Nonetheless I would suggest not using `<hr>` & start using properties like `border-bottom` or so to get the separator effect.

Comment: Why I don't see that being applied in JSfiddle?

Comment: You can.. **Inspect the area(Ctrl + Shift + i) >> Choose the <hr> under Attachment & Add attach >> Check the styles applied on the right side pane(top most)**. The style will show from which file it is getting applied from including the line number

Comment: LOL..Oops.. I thought you were the question poster.

Comment: as you can see there isn't that line in bootstrap anymore https://snag.gy/BJRiy7.jpg

Comment: try the one that's in between the 'attachment' & 'add attachment' sections. exactly 6 lines below the one you have selected in the screengrab.